# SCP error 'unable to open'

Tags: windows-7, networking, ssh, putty, scp

So, I set up a SSH server (freeSSH, win7) and can connect to it just fine with PuTTY. 
I then tried to use pscp to transfer a file (foobar.txt, from client to server). 
I cd-ed to the dir pscp.exe was in, then did `pscp.exe foobar.txt user@IP:C:\Users...` and got the response `user@IP's password:`.

At this I promptly typed in the password, to be met with `pscp: unable to open C:\Users...: permission denied`. 
The error for getting the password wrong is different, more specifically; `Access denied`.

(IP is the remote IP, and C:\Users... is the remote filepath)

Comment: Do you happen to have any spaces in your filepath? `pscp` seems to [hate spaces](http://superuser.com/questions/532919/how-to-use-pscp-to-copy-file-from-unix-machine-to-windows-machine-where-target-p)

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that the directory you're trying to copy to does not have sufficient permissions for `user` to write to.

- Is the directory you are copying to under `user`'s home directory on the destination system?
- Does the destination directory actually exist?
- What are the permissions of `foobar.txt`? (user may not be able to access the source file so cannot copy it to destination)

To check file permissions on a Windows system:

- Right click on the file/folder you want to check
- Select `Properties` from the menu
- Select the `Security` tab

You should then be able to see the user & group who own the file along with permissions for `Everyone`.

*Note: I don't have enough reputation to comment but hope that these questions will help narrow down the cause.*

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Apologies! I wanted to try and help but didn't have high enough rep... Getting close now though! Happy for this to be removed if it's an issue.